# Can I get a ui-grid with selection without check column?

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Can I get a ui-grid with selection plugin enabled but without check column showing?

My html mark

```
<div class="grid300" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection></div>
```

My js config

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'dirs',
    enableSelectAll: false,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, onRowSelection);
    },
    columnDefs: columnDefs
};
```

Expected Result:

My grid without the first checkbox column.

Answer (score 3):

As stated at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection:

> By default the module will provide a row header with checkboxes that allow selection of individual rows. If you set the enableRowHeaderSelection gridOption to false, then the row header is hidden and a click on the row will result in selection of that row.

so, just add enableRowHeaderSelection: false

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false, 
  data: 'dirs',
  enableSelectAll: false,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, onRowSelection);
  },
  columnDefs: columnDefs
};
```